# Yellowbrick: PredictionError dimensionality issue

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, yellowbrick

I'm trying to use the [yellowbrick](https://www.scikit-yb.org/) [PredictionError](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/regressor/peplot.html) and am running into strange dimensionality issues. I am using yellowbrick version 1.4.

Suppose we had this very simple linear regression:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from yellowbrick.regressor import PredictionError, ResidualsPlot

X = pd.DataFrame({
    "x1": np.linspace(1, 1000, 800),
    "x2": np.linspace(2, 500, 800),
    "x3": np.random.rand(800) * 50
})
y = pd.DataFrame().assign(y_val = 3 * X.x1 + 4 * X.x2 + X.x3)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42
)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now I want to run diagnostics. [ResidualsPlot](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/regressor/residuals.html) works easily, passing in the Pandas data structures unmodified:

```
rp = ResidualsPlot(model)
rp.fit(X_train, y_train)
rp.score(X_test, y_test)
rp.show()
# produces graphic (not shown)
```

However, when I try to use [PredictionError](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/regressor/peplot.html):

```
pe = PredictionError(model)
pe.fit(X_train, y_train)
pe.score(X_test, y_test)
```

The call to `score()` produces this error message:

```
File ~/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yellowbrick/bestfit.py:141, in draw_best_fit(X, y, ax, estimator, **kwargs)
    139 # Verify that y is a (n,) dimensional array
    140 if y.ndim > 1:
--> 141     raise YellowbrickValueError(
    142         "y must be a (1,) dimensional array not {}".format(y.shape)
    143     )
    145 # Uses the estimator to fit the data and get the model back.
    146 model = estimator(X, y)

YellowbrickValueError: y must be a (1,) dimensional array not (264, 1)
```

Now I realize the type of `y` is `DataFrame`. If I change it to `Series`, the code will work, e.g.:

```
# Same as before, for reference
y = pd.DataFrame().assign(y_val= 3 * X.x1 + 4 * X.x2 + X.x3)

# Change to Series here
y = y["y_val"]
```

The conversion to `Series` certainly is a viable workaround but I'm wondering why it's the case here and not with `ResidualsPlot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a draw_best_fit function that PredictionError accesses that checks to see if y is only one dimension and this function isn't used in ResidualPlot.  Maybe you can submit a PR suggesting a fix.  https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick/

Comment: Thank you! I'll dig into it this week and work towards a PR!